# Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative in java.library.path

Tags: amazon-managed-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I,m trying to do a aws java 11 lambda fabric client using fabric-sdk-java 2.2.21 for amazon managed blockchain using hyperledger fabric 2.2, but when I run the lambda I got this error "Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative in java.library.path: [/var/task, /usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]".
I have tried several solutions but none work:
I also create a layer with a zip (/java/lib) with io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative.so but didn't work for me.
I've run out of ideas. I would appreciate if someone help me.